# Map dictionary values, instead of dictionary keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['10/2/2011', '11/2/2011', '12/2/2011', '13/2/2011'],
                'Event':[0,1,2,3],
                'Cost':[10000, 5000, 15000, 2000]})
```

Dictionary:

```
dict = {'Music' : 0, 'Poetry' : 1, 'Theatre' : 2, 'Comedy' : 3}
```

If I want to map based on dictionary keys, I use:

```
df['new_column']= df['Event'].map(dict)
```

Is there a way I can map dictionary values, instead of keys?

Comment: What behavior do you want if multiple keys have the same value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use dict comprehension+`map()`:

```
dct= {'Music' : 0, 'Poetry' : 1, 'Theatre' : 2, 'Comedy' : 3}
df['new_column']=df['Event'].map({v:k for k,v in dct.items()})
```

OR

Another way via `replace()`:

```
df['new_column']=df['Event'].replace(dct.values(),dct.keys())
```

output of `df`:

```
    Date    Event   Cost    new_column
0   10/2/2011   0   10000   Music
1   11/2/2011   1   5000    Poetry
2   12/2/2011   2   15000   Theatre
3   13/2/2011   3   2000    Comedy
```

**Note:** Don't assign anything to `dict` function in python